# I should call sess.run(iterator.initializer) in where?

Tags: python, tensorflow

i want to try a code structure:

- train_input_fn_try(): generate data, return feature dict and label; the data will produce from `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random_uniform([100,5]),tf.random_uniform([100],maxval=4,dtype=tf.int32)))`;
- in main func: i called `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` to get classifier, then called `classifier.train(input_fn=lambda :train_input_fn_try(batch_size=3),steps=6)` to train.

but, i found that i must called `sess.run(iterator.initializer)` before `iterator.get_next()`.

I don't know where `sess.run(iterator.initializer)` should be called without destroying the code structure? in main func or in train_input_fn_try func? and how to do?

Here is an example of code that can't work:

```
def train_input_fn_try(batch_size=2,epoch=1,shuffle=True):
    dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random_uniform([100,5]),tf.random_uniform([100],maxval=4,dtype=tf.int32)))
    if shuffle:
        dataset=dataset.shuffle(10000)
    dataset=dataset.repeat(epoch)
    dataset=dataset.batch(batch_size)
    iterator=dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    text,label=iterator.get_next()
    return {"text":text},label

with tf.Session() as sess:
    my_feature_columns=[]
    my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="text",shape=[5]))
    clf=tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
                                   hidden_units=[10,10],n_classes=4)
    clf.train(input_fn=lambda :train_input_fn_try(batch_size=3),steps=6)
```

the runtime error is:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
>        [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,5], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>        [[Node: dnn/head/assert_range/assert_less/Assert/Assert/_106 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_83_dnn/head/assert_range/assert_less/Assert/Assert", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

Comment: If you don't need the `initializing` feature of the `make_initializable_iterator()`, I encourage you to use `make_one_shot_iterator()`. If you really rely on the initialization feature, you could try to encapsulate your iterator in an object to have the possibility to access it outside of the scope of the training function.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside @Lescurel's very on-point comment, the problem you have is that you initialize the iterator in a *different* session than the one you then try to train:

```
def train_input_fn_try(batch_size=2,epoch=1,shuffle=True):
    # [...]
    with tf.Session() as sess: # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This session...
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    text,label=iterator.get_next()
    return {"text":text},label

with tf.Session() as sess: # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ...is NOT the same as this one!
    # [...]
```

The `with tf.Session() as sess:` statement creates a **new** instance of a session and assigns it to `sess` and **that session is cosed once you exit the `with` statement**.

For your code, the best solution is to just use a one-shot iterator, but if you *really* want to use the initializable one, pass `sess` as a parameter to `train_input_fn_try` and remove the `with` statement inside the function:

```
def train_input_fn_try(sess,batch_size=2,epoch=1,shuffle=True):
    # [...]
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    # [...]
```

### Update: why this still doesn't work (with Estimators)

The way the Estimator framework works is approximately:

- Make new graph
- call `input_fn` to set up the input pipeline in the new graph
- call `model_fn` to set up the model in the new graph
- make a `Session` and start a training loopp

When you make the lambda, the `sess` you pass is not the one that will be used by the estimator, so this won't work for you I'm afraid. I am not aware at the moment of ways to use other types of iterators with Estimators, you might have to stick to one-shot iterators.

Comment: i try it just like your last block of code, i pass `sess` to `train_input_fn_try` func, but it raise another error: **`ValueError("Operation %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)`**

Comment: it seem that estimator doesn't support init operation in outside?

Comment: Indeed, that is related to Estimator. I'll edit the answer to provide an explanation of why this won't work, but I can only do this in 1 hour ;)